# Turn a SPAN into an input field?

Tags: javascript

I'm not a programmer and I want to convert a SPAN into an INPUT.
I have next code, but it isn't exactly what I'm searching. it only allows me to delete words, and I want to turn a SPAN completely into an INPUT, cause I have a Firefox add-on to cycle through all inputs with a shortcut.

```
 var i,
 list = document.querySelectorAll(".emailids") 
 for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) 
 { list[i].setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
 }
```

Comment: All of them? On page-load, onclick..?

Comment: well, if possible I'd like to know how for ALL and how for just one of them (dd.emailids:nth-child(4) > span:nth-child(1))

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is change the `outerHTML` property like so:

```
 var i,
       list = document.querySelectorAll(".emailids") 
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) 
    {  list[i].outerHTML="<input type='text' value='"+list[i].innerHTML+"' />";
       list[i].innerHTML=""
    }
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vulpus/SvL9X/1/
What this does it it changes all the `outerHTML`of the spans and sets it's value to the innerHTML or content of the span. Then you set the `innerHTML` to nothing to avoid children of the input

Comment: yeah, it works, but now it shows the <span></span> inside the input. how to avoid that?

Comment: Ok, If you set the `innerHTML` property afterward to nothing. (All update my post)

Comment: It shouldn't have the span now

Comment: No. It still keeps the <span></span>.

Comment: @Sam-Bo It does not. It sets the value of the input to whatever the the content within the span was.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `outerHTML` to replace `.emailids` with an input.

```
list[i].outerHTML = '<input type="text" value="" />';
```

Since you want `.emailids`'s text contents to be the `value` of the input, you can use

```
list[i].textContent
```

But `textContent` can contain quotes, which also delimit `value` attribute, so you must escape them:

```
list[i].textContent.replace(/"/g,'&quot;')
```

---

Full code:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".emailids") 
for (var i = 0, l=list.length; i < l; ++i) {  
    list[i].outerHTML = 
        '<input type="text" value="'
        +list[i].textContent.replace(/"/g,'&quot;')
        +'" />';
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SvL9X/3/)

Comment: Can I ask here for the script to change Firefox tab title when the input has become focused?

Comment: @Sam-Bo You can change `document.title` in a `focus` event handler.